# How to update MySql table row through C# console application?

Tags: c#, mysql, console-application

I am writing a console application and fetch data from MySql table . 
Code :

```
 string connection = "Server=localhoht;Database=data;Uid=root;Pwd=root123";
        MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        MySqlCommand selectData;
        dbcon.Open();
        selectData = dbcon.CreateCommand();
selectData.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, user_name,user_type FROM win_user WHERE user_type=1 ORDER BY user_id ASC ";
        MySqlDataReader juh = selectData.ExecuteReader();
```

And its working fine. Now I want to update a row with the code below :

```
string updatedata = "UPDATE win_user SET user_type='1' WHERE user_id= '1'";
        MySqlDataAdapter MyData = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MyData.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(updatedata, dbcon);
```

But its not working.

Comment: Shouldn't there be one last 'Execute' command?  MyData.Execute()

I am no expert but in my experience there is a final 'Execute' after setting the command text with UpdateCommand

Answer (score 0):

You can run the commend "UPDATE win_user SET user_type='1' WHERE user_id= '1'" in any sql client tools, eg, navicat, to verify wheather it's correct on your mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

The `MySqlDataAdapter` could be used to update rows in a database table using the Update method.
The [Update method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (link is for SqlServer but the concept is the same) has many overload, but basically it requires a DataTable with rows modified in some way `([RowState != DataRowState.Unchanged][2])` so the `MySqlDataAdapter` can pick the rows changed and apply the `DeleteCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `InsertCommand` defined in the adapter

Your code above doesn't shown any kind of interaction with a datatable and you have a call to the Update method so there is no way for the update to occur.

You could, of course execute  directly your command without any adapter involved

**EDITed to change every user_type not 1 to 1**

```
string updatedata = "UPDATE win_user SET user_type=1 WHERE user_type <> 1";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(updatedata, dbcon);  
int numOfRowsChanged = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I want change those row where user_type is not 1 , So i Update user_type = 1 through the code .

Comment: If you want to change ALL rows where user_type is not 1 then you need to change your WHERE condition (or remove the WHERE at all). The code shown in your example updates only the row for user_id = 1. I will update the answer but I need a clarification before. Is the user_type field and Integer in your datatable? If yes you don't use single quotes around value